# org-mode latex preview with png file not work

Tags: org-mode, latex

I would like to preview a latex output as png file and show it in emacs 27.1. My os is ubuntu22.04 and texlive2023. I try code below:

```
#+header: :file ./demo.png :results file drawer :fit yes :border 0.1cm -density 400
#+header: :headers '("\\usepackage{tikz}  \\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,math}")
#+begin_src latex
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\conv}{O{2}mm}{%
  \fpeval{round((#3)/(1#2),#1)}%
}
\definecolor{gold}{HTML}{FFD700}
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{F00000}
\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{0000F0}
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{008000}
\tikzset{
  dot/.style={
    circle,fill=gold,
    draw=black,minimum size=22,line width=6,
    inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.2]
  \coordinate (P1) at (6,6);
  \coordinate (P2) at (22,30);
  \coordinate (P3) at (42,30);
  \coordinate (P4) at (70,24);
  
  \coordinate (C1) at (11.16,16);
  \coordinate (C2) at (16.31,26);
  \coordinate (C3) at (27.69,34);
  \coordinate (C4) at (33.91,32);
  \coordinate (C5) at (50.09,28);
  \coordinate (C6) at (60.04,26);
  
   \draw[line width=8,red]
        (P1)  .. controls (C1) and (C2) ..
        (P2)  .. controls (C3) and (C4) ..
        (P3)  .. controls (C5) and (C6) ..
        (P4);
   \def\arr{
     P1,
     P2,
     P3,
     P4%
     }
   \foreach \m in \arr {
     \path let \p1=(\m) in
         node[dot,label=above:{\conv[0]{cm}{\x1},\conv[0]{cm}{\y1}}] at (\m) {};
     }
\end{tikzpicture}
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:results:
[[file:./demo.png]]
:end:
```

But the output show some text instead of a image.
[image]

Comment: Is your Emacs built with the PNG library? What does `(image-type-available-p 'png)` return?

Comment: Yes, that command return true. so it should support png file.

Comment: Can you display the PNG file using some other program (e.g. ImageMagick's `display` program)?  IOW, is Emacs at fault here or is it something else?

Comment: yes, use other image viewer can open that png file and it's the same as above. so png file iformat is good, but the tool convert from pdf to png looks wrong. it should be something build-in in emacs.

Comment: So you click on the link and it opens a buffer where it shows the text. What happens if you press `C-c C-c` in that buffer? Does it switch to the image?